# Providing data and variable names in a function in R

Tags: r, dplyr

### Goal

I want to provide both the data and variable names in a function. This is because users might provide datasets with different names of the same variables. Following is a reproducible example that throws an error. Please refer me to the relevant resources to fix this problem.

Also, please let me know what are best practices for writing such functions? In the documentation, should I ask a user to rename their columns or provide a dataset with only the required columns?

#### Example

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

dataset1 <- mtcars %>%
  select(mpg, disp, wt)

dataset2 <- mtcars %>%
  select(miles_per_gallon = mpg, displacement_cu_in = disp, weight = wt)
  


my_func <- function(data, var_mileage, var_volume, var_weight){
  
  var_mileage_km_l <- 0.43 * data$var_mileage
  var_volume_l <- 0.016 * data$var_volume
  var_weight_kg <- 0.45 * data$var_weight
  
  m <- lm(var_mileage_km_l ~ var_volume_l + var_weight_kg)
  
  summary(m)
}


my_func(dataset1, mpg, disp, wt)
#> Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...): 0 (non-NA) cases
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

#### Expected Output

I want the function to create the following output regardless of whether a user provides `dataset1` or `dataset2` with corresponding variable names.

```
Call:
lm(formula = var_mileage_km_l ~ var_volume_l + var_weight_kg)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.4657 -0.9994 -0.3304  0.7620  2.7298 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    15.0330     0.9308  16.151 4.91e-16 ***
var_volume_l   -0.4764     0.2470  -1.929  0.06362 .  
var_weight_kg  -3.2019     1.1124  -2.878  0.00743 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.254 on 29 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7809,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7658 
F-statistic: 51.69 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 2.744e-10
```

#### Note

I know that the above can be done by using `{{var}}` in a dataframe context. But as you see, I do not want to do the calculations inside a dataframe. This is just an example, my real problem cannot be solved inside a dataframe.

### EDIT:

Following is my original function. Within the function body, you can see that I use `data$` several times. If the user does not have the same column names as I use it here, the function won't work. This is why I asked about providing the variable names (column names) along with the `data` argument.

```
apply_wiedemann <- function(data,
                            V_DESIRED,
                            FAKTORVmult,
                            BMAXmult,
                            BNULLmult,
                            AXadd,
                            BXadd,
                            angular_vel_threshold,
                            EXadd,
                            OPDVadd
){
  
  
  
  ## Parameters --------------------------------------------------------------------
  V_MAX <- 44
  
  L <- na.omit(unique(data$LV_length_m))
  W <- na.omit(unique(data$LV_width_m))
  
  angular_vel_threshold <- angular_vel_threshold
  CX = sqrt(W / angular_vel_threshold)
  
  BMIN = -8
  AX = L + AXadd 
  
  
  ## Time--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  delta_T <- (data$frames[2] - data$frames[1])/60
  last_time <- (nrow(data) - 1) * delta_T
  Time <- seq(from = 0, to = last_time, by = delta_T)
  
  
  
  
  ## Empty vectors
  BMAX <- rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time)) ### an empty vector 
  vn_complete <- rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time))
  vn_complete[1] <- data$ED_speed_mps[1]
  
  vn1_complete <- data$LV_speed_mps
  dv <- rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time))
  dv[1] <- data$LV_DV_mps[1]
  
  
  xn_complete <- rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time))
  xn_complete[1] <- data$ED_position_m[1]
  
  
  xn1_complete <- data$LV_position_m
  
  
  bn_complete <-rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time))
  
  sn_complete <- rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time))
  sn_complete[1] <- data$LV_spacing_m[1]
  
  
  
  BX <- rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time)) ### an empty vector 
  ABX <- rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time)) ### an empty vector 
  
  SDV <- rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time)) ### an empty vector 
  B_App <- rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time)) ### an empty vector 
  
  bl <- data$LV_acc_mps2
  
  B_Emg <- rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time))
  
  SDX <- rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time))
  
  CLDV <- rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time))
  
  OPDV <- rep(NA_real_, times = length(Time))
  
  cf_state_sim <- rep(NA_character_, times = length(Time))
  
  
  
  ## Unintentional Acceleration and Deceleration when the car is at V_DESIRED
  # BNULL = BNULLmult * (RND4 + NRND) 
  BNULL = BNULLmult 
  
  
  FaktorV = V_MAX / (V_DESIRED + FAKTORVmult * (V_MAX - V_DESIRED))
  
  
  # EX = EXadd + EXmult * (NRND - RND2)
  EX = EXadd
  
  
  for (t in 1:(length(Time)-1)) { 
    
    ## Speed-dependent part of Minimum following distance
    # BX = (BXadd + (BXmult * RND1)) * sqrt(v)
    BX[t] = BXadd * sqrt(min(c(vn_complete[t], vn1_complete[t]), na.rm = TRUE)) ###0.8 | 0.886
    
    ## Minimum following distance
    ABX[t] = AX + BX[t] ### 16.91 | 16.996
    
    
    ## Speed-difference at which driver perceives that the lead vehicle is slow
    SDV[t] = ((sn_complete[t] - AX)/CX)^2 ###0.34 |
    
    
    ## Maximum following distance
    SDX[t] = AX + (EX * BX[t])
    
    
    ## Speed-difference when driver perceives that lead vehicle is slower
    CLDV[t] = SDV[t] * EX^2
    
    
    ## Speed-difference when driver perceives that lead vehicle is faster
    # OPDV = CLDV * (((-1) * OPDVadd) - (OPDVmult * NRND))
    OPDV[t] = CLDV[t] * ((-1) * OPDVadd)
    
    
    
    if (is.na(sn_complete[t]) | is.na(dv[t])) {
      
      BMAX[t] <- BMAXmult * (V_MAX - (vn_complete[t] * FaktorV)) 
      
      bn_complete[t] <- BMAX[t]
      
      cf_state_sim[t] <- "free_driving"  
      
    } else if (sn_complete[t] <= ABX[t]) {
      
      B_Emg[t] = 0.5 * ((dv[t])^2 / (AX - sn_complete[t])) + bl[t] + 
        (BMIN * ((ABX[t] - sn_complete[t]) / (ABX[t] - AX)))
      
      bn_complete[t] <- ifelse(B_Emg[t] < BMIN | B_Emg[t] > 0, BMIN, B_Emg[t])
      
      cf_state_sim[t] <- "emergency_braking"
      
    } else if (sn_complete[t] < SDX[t]) {
      
      if ( dv[t] > CLDV[t]) {
        
        bn_complete[t] <- BNULL
        
        cf_state_sim[t] <- "following"
        
      } else if (dv[t] > OPDV[t]) {
        
        bn_complete[t] <- BNULL
        
        cf_state_sim[t] <- "following"
        
      } else {
        
        BMAX[t] <- BMAXmult * (V_MAX - (vn_complete[t] * FaktorV)) 
        
        bn_complete[t] <- BMAX[t]
        
        cf_state_sim[t] <- "free_driving"
        
      }
      
    } else {
      
      if (dv[t] > SDV[t]) { 
        
        B_App[t] = 0.5 * ((dv[t])^2 / (ABX[t] - sn_complete[t])) + bl[t]
        
        bn_complete[t] <- ifelse(B_App[t] < BMIN, BMIN, B_App[t])
        
        cf_state_sim[t] <- "approaching"
        
      } else {
        
        BMAX[t] <- BMAXmult * (V_MAX - (vn_complete[t] * FaktorV)) ###2.19
        
        bn_complete[t] <- BMAX[t]
        
        cf_state_sim[t] <- "free_driving"
        
      }
    }
    
    vn_complete[t+1] <- vn_complete[t] + (bn_complete[t] * delta_T)
    
    vn_complete[t+1] <- ifelse(vn_complete[t+1] < 0, 0, vn_complete[t+1])
    
    xn_complete[t+1] <- xn_complete[t] - (vn_complete[t] * delta_T) + (0.5 * bn_complete[t] * (delta_T)^2)
    
    sn_complete[t+1] <- xn_complete[t+1] - xn1_complete[t+1]
    
    dv[t+1] <- vn_complete[t+1] - vn1_complete[t+1]
    

    
    
  }
  
  frspacing_pred <- sn_complete - L
  
  
  SSE <- sum(((frspacing_pred - data$LV_frspacing_m)^2)/ abs(data$LV_frspacing_m), na.rm = TRUE)/sum(abs(data$LV_frspacing_m), na.rm = TRUE)
  
  return(SSE)
}
```

Hopefully, it is now clear to everyone that this problem cannot be solved within a dataframe context. Thanks to @MrFlick, I understand what to do now. I also experimented with `enquo` and `data %>% pull(!! var_name)` and it seems to do what `eval(substitute())` does.

Comment: Why it cant be done in a df context, that is extremely rare given dplyr ease of use and the existence of rowise operations. lm is made to work with data frames, unless you find a function that accepts vector it won`t work, maybe someone tried to copy the philosophy of scikit learn somewhere

Comment: @Bruno, modeling is not the purpose here. I want to use both data and variable names for running a car-following model. Since that is a pretty long function with several inputs and also does recursive calculations on vectors, I opted to use a small example. That calculation can't be done in a data frame unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like a very unusual way to write an R function, but you could do

```
my_func <- function(data, var_mileage, var_volume, var_weight){
  
  eval(substitute({
    var_mileage_km_l <- 0.43 * var_mileage
    var_volume_l <- 0.016 * var_volume
    var_weight_kg <- 0.45 * var_weight    
    
    m <- lm(var_mileage_km_l ~ var_volume_l + var_weight_kg)
    
    summary(m)
  }), envir = data)
}
```

The `substitute()` injects the symbols you pass as the column names into the expression. Then you can evaluate it in the context of the data.frame.

Alternatively you could do something like

```
my_func <- function(data, var_mileage, var_volume, var_weight){
  
  var_mileage <- eval(substitute(var_mileage), data)
  var_volume <- eval(substitute(var_volume), data)
  var_weight <- eval(substitute(var_weight), data)
  
  var_mileage_km_l <- 0.43 * var_mileage
  var_volume_l <- 0.016 * var_volume
  var_weight_kg <- 0.45 * var_weight
    
  m <- lm(var_mileage_km_l ~ var_volume_l + var_weight_kg)
  
  summary(m)
}
```

Or one other common trick is to turn the column names as strings.

```
my_func <- function(data, var_mileage, var_volume, var_weight){
   
  var_mileage_km_l <- 0.43 * data[[var_mileage]]
  var_volume_l <- 0.016 * data[[var_volume]]
  var_weight_kg <- 0.45 * data[[var_weight]]    
    
  m <- lm(var_mileage_km_l ~ var_volume_l + var_weight_kg)
  
  summary(m)
}
my_func(dataset1, "mpg", "disp", "wt")
```

Comment: Thanks. This solves my problem. I understand that using this function for this modeling example is unusual but that was just an example. I will add my actual function to the question later to show why I could not do the calculation inside the dataframe. I did not add it in the first place because everyone would have downvoted me as they did in a previous question.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you're wanting something other than this? It may be too simplistic

```
library(dplyr)

dataset1 <- mtcars %>%
  select(mpg, disp, wt)``

dataset2 <- mtcars %>%
  select(mpg, disp, wt) %>%
  rename(miles_per_gallon = mpg, displacement_cu_in = disp, weight = wt)



my_func <- function(data, var_mileage, var_volume, var_weight){
  
  var_mileage_km_l <- 0.43 * data[,1]
  var_volume_l <- 0.016 * data[,2]
  var_weight_kg <- 0.45 * data[,3]
  
  m <- lm(var_mileage_km_l ~ var_volume_l + var_weight_kg)
  
  summary(m)
}


my_func(dataset1, mpg, disp, wt)

my_func(dataset2, mpg, disp, wt)
```

Comment: This would only work if I ask the user of the function to arrange the dataset by position and remove all other columns. Also, just the data argument would suffice. But I am not sure if this is a good practice if I want to provide the function in a package.